# R markdown: Accessing variable from code chunk before it's evaluation

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I'm producing a pdf report with rmd. Before some plots I write some explanations about them, but their code and data haven't been produced yet, they are in code chunks after these explanations. The problem is, I need to access a R variable that is evaluated in one of those chunks.
In other words, I want to access a R variable before it's evaluation.
There is an example below:

````
---
title: ''
geometry: left=18mm, right=19mm, top=20mm, bottom=25mm
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{multicol}
    - \usepackage{caption}
    - \usepackage{graphicx}
    - \usepackage{grffile}
    - \usepackage{float}
    - \usepackage{units}
    - \usepackage{environ}
    - \usepackage{setspace}
    - \usepackage{colortbl}
    - \usepackage{xcolor}
    - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    - \usepackage{subfig}
    - \usepackage{longtable}
    - \usepackage{pdflscape}
    - \usepackage{indentfirst}
    - \usepackage{setspace}
tables: true
keep_tex: true
indent: true
fontsize: 12pt
---

```{r global_options, include=FALSE}

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE)
opts_knit$set(eval.after = "fig.cap")
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.pos = '!h')
options(knitr.kable.NA = '')

```

I want to access a R variable here, for example, `r variable`, that is in a chunck after this text.

```{r}

variable <- 2+2

```
````

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, could you be a bit more clear please?

Comment: Sorry for my language. I'm producing a pdf report with rmd. Before some plots I write some explanations about them, but their code and data haven't been produced yet, they are after these explanations. Sorry for my english

Comment: As far as I know you can't access those data/plot if you have not run them in the R chunk. You could run them in the ``R Setup`` if you want to have access to those at all time in your R Markdown document.

Comment: I will try to work with that @Gainz , thanks!

Comment: @DanielOliveira I can write you a code example of what I mean if you want?

Comment: That would be great @Gainz , thanks!

Comment: It''s unclear what value that variable would take. What if you had multiple chunks that changed the value of the variable, both before and after where you want to use it in the text? Rmarkdown wouldn't have a way to know which value you wanted. Do you really need to talk about their specific values before they are created? If so, maybe just create those values in the chunk before you talk about them and separate that from the plotting code.

Comment: I agree with the comment over me tho, why are you not simply making the variable before the text? Anyway see my example (sorry had to do it as an answer), the variable are inserted in the ``R options`` allowing them to be available at all time in the document.

Comment: So you can simply talk about those variables and call them after.

Comment: I agree with you, @MrFlick, but I was curious because knitr has a function for evaluate a plot caption, for example, after the chunk is runned, and I wanted to know if something similar was possible in this case. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Thank you very much for the example, @Gainz!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your variable are staying the same during the document, I suggest you insert them in the `R options` chunks if you're going to use them more than one time.

````
---
title: 'A nice title'
geometry: left=18mm, right=19mm, top=20mm, bottom=25mm
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{multicol}
    - \usepackage{caption}
    - \usepackage{graphicx}
    - \usepackage{grffile}
    - \usepackage{float}
    - \usepackage{units}
    - \usepackage{environ}
    - \usepackage{setspace}
    - \usepackage{colortbl}
    - \usepackage{xcolor}
    - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    - \usepackage{subfig}
    - \usepackage{longtable}
    - \usepackage{pdflscape}
    - \usepackage{indentfirst}
    - \usepackage{setspace}
tables: true
keep_tex: true
indent: true
fontsize: 12pt
---

```{r global_options, include=FALSE}

# packages
library(knitr)

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE)
opts_knit$set(eval.after = "fig.cap")
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.pos = '!h')
options(knitr.kable.NA = '')

## preload your R variables here ##
variable_1 <- 2+2
variable_2 <- c("a", "b", "c")
variable_3 <- head(mtcars[, 2:5])
variable_4 <- plot(variable_3)
## preload your R variables here ##

```

The variable already runned/loaded in the ``R options`` chunk will be available at all time in the R Markdown document.

```{r}
print("Here is the value of the variable_1 :")
print(variable_1)
```
````